# Create a certificate to sign a program but file to apply trust

Tags: openssl, sign

I create a pfx by openssl by

```
openssl genrsa -out key8192.key 8192

openssl req -new -key key8192.key –out KKROOT.crt
```

[input something]

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out KKROOT.pfx -inkey key8192.key -in KKROOT.crt
```

and then install KKROOT.pfx into Current User's Personal

I use this certificate sign a progrom by a sign tool.

install certificate into Root trust but it is not trust really and show:
a certificate basic constraints extension has not been observed.
This certification authority is not allowed to issue certificates or cannot be used as an end-entity certificate.(in file properties -> signature -> Details ->View certificate)

What can I do next?

Any help is welcome.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

solved!

```
openssl ca -in cs.csr -out cs.crt -cert KKROOT.crt -keyfile key8192.key -config  C:\openssl\ssl\openssl.cnf

openssl req -new -key key8192.key -out cs.csr -config  C:\openssl\ssl\openssl.cnf
```

is okay.